# Attaching Events to Elements in an Angularjs Based UI in an Each loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Array of Objects in `AngularJS` which consists of:

- EmployeeComments
- ManagerComments
- ParticipantsComments.

```js
[{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Question1",
  "ManagerComment": "This was a Job Wel Done",
  "EmployeeComment": "Wow I am Surprised",
  "ParticipantArray": [{
      "id": "1",
      "comment": "Oh i Dont think So"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "comment": "Oh i believe the same"
    }

  ]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "title": "Question 2",
  "ManagerComment": "This was a Job Wel Done 1",
  "EmployeeComment": "Wow I am Surprised 1",
  "ParticipantArray": [{
      "id": "1",
      "comment": "Oh i Dont think So 1"
    }

  ]
}];
```

I iterate through this object to get textarea with comments from Object.

I have to show Save/Edit buttons in front of each textarea to edit comments , update comments or add any new comments.

I am not sure how to do dat as i am looking for a this like object which just works on individual textarea rather than all the textarea fields. Any suggestions.

Comment: Please provide the work you have done so far in a plnkr or something similar. Basically what you have to do is to use ng-repeat and bind the data with ng-model, then write the logic for save/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CoFpux44M2FBWsAz2RZZ?p=preview) showing how this can be done.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tableData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Question1",
    "ManagerComment": "This was a Job Wel Done",
    "EmployeeComment": "Wow I am Surprised",
    "ParticipantArray": [{
        "id": "1",
        "comment": "Oh i Dont think So"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "comment": "Oh i believe the same"
      }

    ]
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Question 2",
    "ManagerComment": "This was a Job Wel Done 1",
    "EmployeeComment": "Wow I am Surprised 1",
    "ParticipantArray": [{
        "id": "1",
        "comment": "Oh i Dont think So 1"
      }

    ]
  }];

  $scope.tableDataCopy = angular.copy( $scope.tableData );

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.tableData = angular.copy( $scope.tableDataCopy );
  }

});
```

Basically the controller just contains your data, together with  a copy of it so that we do not write directly to the model (hence there would be no need for a save function).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="data in tableDataCopy">
        Manager comment:
        <textarea ng-disabled="!edit" ng-model="data.ManagerComment"></textarea>

        <br>
        Employee comment:
        <textarea ng-disabled="!edit" ng-model="data.EmployeeComment"></textarea>
          <div ng-repeat="participant in data.ParticipantArray">
            Participant {{participant.id}}: <textarea ng-disabled="!edit" ng-model="participant.comment"></textarea>

          </div>
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button><button ng-click="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>

      {{tableData}}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{tableDataCopy}}
  </body>

</html>
```

This is just a very simple example of how to use repeaters, data binding and click events.

I am sure that you will be able to change the logic according to your specific needs from this example.

Edit: Updated the plnkr with individual controls

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="data in tableDataCopy track by $index">
        Manager comment:
        <textarea ng-disabled="!editManager" ng-model="data.ManagerComment"></textarea>
        <button ng-click="tableData[$index].ManagerComment = data.ManagerComment">Save</button><button ng-click="editManager = !editManager">Edit</button>
        <br>
        Employee comment:
        <textarea ng-disabled="!editEmployee" ng-model="data.EmployeeComment"></textarea>
        <button ng-click="tableData[$index].EmployeeComment = data.EmployeeComment">Save</button><button ng-click="editEmployee = !editEmployee">Edit</button>

        <div ng-repeat="participant in data.ParticipantArray">
          Participant {{participant.id}}: <textarea ng-disabled="!participant.edit" ng-model="participant.comment"></textarea>
          <button ng-click="tableData[$parent.$index].ParticipantArray[$index].comment = participant.comment">Save</button><button ng-click="participant.edit = !participant.edit">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>

      {{tableData}}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{tableDataCopy}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry not to mention that Save , Edit etc is against each textarea so my main problem is having individual controls of saving editing disabling etc.

Comment: @sushilbharwani I have updated the plnkr with individual controls.

Comment: @sushilbharwani did this cover your needs or do you have more questions?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat to iterate through your object . assign each comment to a model in text area . So when ever you are going to edit or update that comment that value would be reflected in your object using two way binding of angular .